# To show Galois extension is simple by using Galois correspondence

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Galois correspondence can be proved by using primitive element theorem.

Here,I want to prove

> Every Galois extension is simple extension, using galois
> correspondence.

How can I do that with Galois correspondence theory?Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the question is exactly asking for, but here is an argument using the Galois correspondence:
Let $F/K$ be a *finite* Galois extension. Then by the Galois correspondence $F/K$ only has finitely many intermediate fields as the Galois group $G(F/K)$ is finite and hence has only finitely many subgroups. This implies that $F/K$ is simple. (In general an extension is simple and algebraic iff it has only finitely many intermediate fields, this is a variant of the primitive element theorem.)